# Responsive Site not loading on mobiles after design change

Tags: php, .htaccess, responsive-design

Not actually me but my clients are facing caching related issue.My website design was out dated few days back i implemented new design layout and uploaded site to live.

after uploading i am getting complaints from few not all of the clients that website in mobiles is not loading properly, but when i test it in my devices it loads everything ok.

website url: http://www.mobitairportparking.co.uk

I know its caching issue for those clients who had loaded my old website once in their phones. to sort this issue out i have used following but problem still not solved any one guide me what could be the issue?

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

similarly, i have used .htaccess to restrict caching but no use.

Comment: Have you tried adding random parameter to resources? `styles.css?nocache=<?php echo rand(0, 99999); ?>`

Comment: hmm, i never tried that, it might be the solution, wait let me try and update you.

Comment: man this has solved the issue you are great post as an answer let me mark it love you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force browser to always reload resources instead of loading it from cache. Just append some random parameter to resource

```
styles.css?nocache=<?php echo rand(0, 99999); ?>
```